# How to execute selenium scripts in Chrome GUI browser in AWS - Linux through jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I wanted to know if Chrome GUI browser can be installed in EC2 instances - Linux. I have a situation to run some Selenium java tests and company wants running it on AWS EC2 instance. So wanted to know if a GUI Chrome browser can be installed in EC2 instance?
What are the requirements for executing selenium scripts in Chrome GUI browser in EC2 instances.

I google many stuffs but didn't get perfect guide to this.
Please help.

Comment: [Swathi Samyuktha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7730839) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67123992) saying "You can use VNC viewer. Please refer to [https://medium.com/@vikram.amith/how-to-run-selenium-ui-tests-on-aws-ec2-instance-93caf568917d](https://medium.com/@vikram.amith/how-to-run-selenium-ui-tests-on-aws-ec2-instance-93caf568917d)"